# circular reference in class in python

Tags: python, class, pandas, methods

I have a problem with below design. I am looking for a vectorized solution for below circular reference problem. `Value` (calculated by func1) uses the content from `number` (calculated by func2), `number` gets increased by `Value` afterwards and everything will be produced in a dataframe via build().

```
class test(object):
    def __init__(self, bool, start=100):
        self.start = start
        self.bool = bool
        self.value = self.func1()
        self.number = self.func2()

    def func1(self):
        if bool==True:
            value =  **`here value from func2`**/ 2
        else:
            value = 0
        return value

    def func2(self):
        number =  start + self.value 
        return number

    def build(self):
        df = pd.DataFrame()

        df['bool'] = self.bool
        df['value']= self.value
        df['number'] = self.number
```

so in the end the dataframe should look like this:

```
bool = pd.Series([False, True, False, True, False,.....])

           bool       value      number  
Index 
  0        False        0         100
  1        True        50         100
  2        False        0         150
  3        True        75         150
  4        False        0         225
```

my question is: how can I create this with classes and separate methods for `value`  and `number` without iteration? The problem is that `value` depends on `number`and vice versa (circular reference). 
EDIT: although not modeled in this way here the number could be a cash account and value a certain number of shares that can be bought depending on the account size. account size then increases/decreases based on what happened to the shares. The main difficulty how to define the formula used for `number` (the account). you have a starting value but then in needs to increase depending on the future. but if you write like:

```
   number = start + self.value ((which are the proceeds/results      of other columns))
```

It does not work in the first row because the `self.value` does not yet exist. therefore I used the term circular reference.

Comment: Try and describe what you want to do without describing how your doing it.  I am not quite following what you are trying to do there with the description in the last paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you describe, I think you are trying to implement some sorts of class which construct the list "dynamically". While I think it is better to separate the task into two: one is form the `DataFrame`; second is to `update` it.

Below is my implementation of the class to form the `DataFrame` based on a `Bool`  array and the values.

```
class test(object):
    def __init__(self, _bool, v, start=100):
        self._bool = _bool
        self.v = v
        self.df = pd.DataFrame()
        self.vout = []
        self.start = start
        self.contruct()

    def contruct(self):
        i=0
        for b in self._bool:
            if b:
                self.vout.append(self.v[i])
                i += 1
            else:
                self.vout.append(0)

    def build(self):
        self.df['bool']=self._bool
        self.df['value']= self.vout
        self.df['sum'] = self.df['value'].cumsum() + self.start
        return self.df


_bool = pd.Series([False, True, False, True, False])
_v = [50, 75]

a = test(_bool, _v)
df= a.build()

print df

Out[48]:
    bool  value  sum
0  False      0  100
1   True     50  150
2  False      0  150
3   True     75  225
4  False      0  225
```

FYI, when you define the attribute, you shouldn't use `bool` as it is python reversed namespace and will cause confusion to interpreter as well as to people who read you code.

Comment: how can I create the values _v from columns 'sum'?

Comment: @Al_Iskander, could you pleas elaborate more? I don't quite understand

Comment: my main issue is that 'values' depend on 'numbers' and next row of 'numbers' depends on 'values'. I tried to boil down to simple calculations without many inputs. in real it's an account (numbers) and you calculate the possible number of shares (values) that depends on account size. and after the sale of shares account increases/ decreases. without looping I found no solution myself.

Comment: do you see my issue @mathmax? My question is how to produce the values in the 'value' column. In your example you introduce them as given. But in fact tHey are a result of a formula that relates to the sum column, for example sum / 2. How can I accomplish this in the given framework and possibly without iteration?

Comment: I tried to make the whole issue more clear in (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37653822/vectorized-backtest-creation-of-pandas-dataframe)