# vectorized backtest creation of pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization

This is my final try after posting several questions that might have been badly addressed/described. I want to achive this DataFrame as result:

```
        Signal   price  buy_units   sell_units   cashflow  balance
   Index
      0     0       40          0         0           0     100000
      1     1       50       2000         0      -100000         0
      2    -1      100          0     -2000      +200000    200000  
      3     1       50       4000         0      -200000         0
      4    -1       70          0     -4000      +280000    280000
```

It's a stock trading strategy backtest. When `Signal` is ==1 `buy_units` is equal to current `balance`(value from prior row) divided by `price`. `balance` then becomes reduced by `cashflow` (that is units x price*-1). The remainder should be self-explanatory.
The problem: calculating `buy_units` without iteration but in vectorized fashion. Who has an idea how to solve this?

ultimately I would like to design this in a class with a "Calculate units" and "calculate balance" method but this is not necessary in first step.

Comment: It seems like you need to dynamically populate balance column (`buy units` is affected by `balance`, `balance` is affected by `cashflow` and `cashflow` is affected by `buy units` right?) And I am definitely not an expert but it seems like a job that requires loops.

Comment: @ayhan, this is most probably the reason why I could not figure it out so far. Strange that the answer relating to shift() disappeared, I wanted to give it another look but what you state confirms my view. What makes me wonder is that the problem is easily solved in Excel without any script but becomes more complex in pandas.

Comment: They might have deleted it to take another look or edit. I agree that some operations are very natural in Excel that you can do very easily but when you try to do the same thing in pandas it becomes complicated. It is probably because the operation itself is iterative.

Comment: @Al_Iskander, I deleted my answer because it did not seem correct. Please find my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

If `-1` and `+1` signals always alternate as in the example, then the balance in step `n+2` is equal to the balance in step `n` multiplied by the price return between `n+1` and `n+2`.

I use the cumulated product to translate this into vectorized operations in pandas:

```
# initialize balance
df['balance'] = 0.0
df.balance.iloc[0] = 10000.0

# calculate returns
df['return'] = df.price / df.price.shift()

# calculate balance where signal is -1
df.loc[df.Signal == -1, 'balance'] = \
    df.balance.iloc[0] * df.loc[df.Signal == -1, 'return'].cumprod()
```

The cashflows and number of units can easily be computed from the balance.

Comment: I had it in mind but probably used wrongly. What I did was df.balance.shift(1) in order to address the prior row...your solution seems to be in the right direction

Comment: many thanks. The signals do not necessarily alternate directly. There can be 0's in between.

Comment: the suggestion does not work for my purpose. Also the shift() did not work. I think there is no vectorized solution as @ayhan said earlier above.

Comment: What do you mean, the shift did not work? What version of pandas (`pandas.__version__`) are you using?

Comment: We would need the exact rules of what happens when a `0` follows a `1` or a `-1`. But it's true, unless we find a way to simplify the problem mathematically, then there is probably no vectorized solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a temporary dataframe in order to do your computation:

```
temp = df[df.balance == 1]
```

Then perform computations on this dataframe:

```
df.ix[df.balance == 1,'buy_units'] = temp.balance/temp.price
```

And delete the temporary dataframe:

```
%reset selective -f temp
```